# Non-static inner object in class

Tags: scala, static, lift

I am trying to create a builder for my form fields and I come with something like:

```
class Select(name:String) {
  object cell extends RequestVar("all")
  /* Do some stuff with name and cell */
}

val fruitsField = new Select("fruits")
val drinksField = new Select("drinks")
```

Now I can do:

```
fruitsField.cell.set("tomato")
drinksField.cell.get // returns "tomato"
```

When using those fields I realized that `cell` was shared by `fruits` and `drinks`. I know that it is the normal behavior but is there a way to have this inner object `cell` to be non-static?

**EDIT**

I tried the following but it has the same behavior:

```
class Select(name:String) {
  class ReqVar extends RequestVar("all")
  val cell = new ReqVar
  /* Do some stuff with name and cell */
}
```

Comment: what is the implementation of get and set?

Comment: Hi, it is in the Liftweb framework: http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/net/liftweb/http/RequestVar.html

Comment: I'm missing something here. set and get are defined on RequestVar, but you are calling them on Select ... confused I am.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while building the example, I hope it is more clear now. 

I think that the problem comes from the fact that I don't know how to make a non static inner object in a class in Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attention, the Lift documentation (2.4-M4) states about [RequestVars](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.RequestVar) (and SessionVars):

> If you find it necessary to create a RequestVar subclass of which there may be more than one instance, it is necessary to override the nameSalt() method to return a unique salt value for each instance to prevent name collisions.

So you will have to do something like this:

```
class Select(name:String) {
  val cell = new RequestVar("all") {
    override def __nameSalt = "select_cell_" + name
  }
  /* Do some stuff with name and cell */
}
```

Of course this will only work if there exists only one instance of Select with a given name per Request.

**EDIT**

Based on what you just posted

```
class Select(name:String) {
  class ReqVar extends RequestVar("all") {
    override def __nameSalt = "select_reqvar_cell_" + name
  }

  val cell = new ReqVar
  /* Do some stuff with name and cell */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is anything wrong with

```
val cell = new RequestVar("all")
```

?

Comment: No, I use them a lot and nothing is wrong with the implementation.